# Directus and Sveltekit app - 403 error yet credentials are correct

Tags: sveltekit, directus

I am building a site using sveltekit and directus. I have set up my directus on a VM, made a new collection called frontPage & set up a new role and gave it super user access and made an account there. On the sveltekit side I installed the SDK and was following the docs. I have a config file called initlogin.ts where I put credentials:
[image]

I then tried to bring that data into my sveltekit frontpage like so:
[image]

the account is under admin roles:
[image]

but my page gives me these console errors:
[image]

what am I missing here? Please note I am relatively new to Javascript so my code is not the best you've seen.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, you're context-switching between synchronous and asynchronous.

In `+page.svelte` on line 12, you're attempting to console.log the results of an async function, this results in `> Pending{<pending>}`. The correct way would be `initLogin().then(result => console.log({result}))`

**Secondly**, you're trying to load an about page that requires a property of `data` to be provided that you have not provided in your template, this is resulting in `<About> was created without the expected prop 'data'`

**Thirdly**, you will have security issues if you are planning to have a username and password compiled into the code like that.

**Fourthly** Your page hitting a 403 unathorized is because of the async nature of the code and how you have written it. You can see in the console that the "login success message" comes after your 403 error, this is because of the way you have formatted your code and the login and fetch are running in parallel.

Comment: ok. I have changed the code to the one you've suggested for line 12. Thank you. The second issue was cause by the sveltekit plugin I am using in vs code which makes .svelte files from a menu but it preloads the script section with default imports that I hadn't checked so I commented it out for now. The third thing about the security issues. How would you recommend I do that? I have seen some youtube channels use .env file for that. is that better? Lastly, I understand that svelte uses async code so thought I had do so on the request but I am seeing that login runs last

Comment: .env's are safer, but you still need to ensure usernames and passwords are not compiled into code. I suggest using an access token to avoid compiling passwords (Generate a Token under Users).

—— For the last point, yes it uses async. The problem you have made is all of your code is async (running in parallel), it is your job to enforce a synchronous pattern for the login so that subsequent authed requests can then run asynchronously... In your `initLogin`, try change line 16 to `await initLogin()` and remove the .then.else. This should force the script to wait before it exports on line 22